# Regex: find custom substring like "(123)", "(ABC)", "(+++)"

Tags: java, regex

How can i write the regex for this:

available list: `"some (123)", "other (1BC)", "new (+++)", " do not match"`

the user enters: `"(1"`

looking for substring with brackets and some text inside.

But this is crashing

```
PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 3
\b(1 
  ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
```

Comment: Im confused... What is your input and what is your expected output? Also, please post some code.

Comment: The unclosed group error is telling you that you need to either escape the `(` character (like `\(`), or have a matching `)` for it if you want a capture group instead of a literal `(`.

Comment: Is it an option to use [String.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing the user input `(1` directly to the pattern compiler. The pattern compiler is expeting a regex, so when it tried to interpret `(1` it sees the `(` and thinks its a capture group opening. What you have to do is escape the `(` by adding a `\`. Now how exactly you want to do this is dependent on your design. You might just want to tell the user that he is entering a regex, or you might want to make your own function to escape regex special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure of your requirements, but If you want the content with the brackets `(your content)` use something like this

```
(?<=\()(.+?)(?=\))
```

It shall match

```
123
1BC
+++
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got something like this right now:

```
String userInput = "(1";
String realPattern = "\\b" + userInput;
// use realPattern
```

I think you just need to [escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) your input before using it.

```
String userInput = "(1";
String escapedInput = Pattern.quote(userInput);
String realPattern = "\\b" + escapedInput;
// use realPattern
```

If this isn't right, please provide expected inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Question is little vague but if you're trying to compile user input as regular expression then you must use: [`Pattern.quote(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to avoid unexpected errors like this as user input may contain special regex symbols:

```
String regex = Pattern.quote(input);
```